# Update the sqlite attached database based on any change in the main database in C

Tags: c, sqlite, transparency, replication

I have a sample application in C connected to the sqlite database. I have to replicate this DB (transparent replication) **on the same server** (on different disks). To explain my question better, what I need is:

- Create one or two slave/backup databases which are synced with the main db. e.g., when I write in the main db, the backup db/dbs will be updated as well. Also, for read, if the main db crashed, the application should read from the other backup db.

I know sqlite does not support replication and I searched a lot and found some solutions but they are mostly for replication across multiple servers or for MySQL.

What came to my mind was creating a new DB and copy all data from the main db to the slave:

```
ATTACH '/root/litereplica/litereplica-master/sqlite3.6/fuel_transaction_1_backup.db' AS backup;  //This attached a new empty db to the main db

CREATE TABLE backup.fuel_transaction_1 AS SELECT * FROM main.fuel_transaction_1;
```

Now, I need to synch this backup db with the main db. So, I have to update the slave based on the change on the main db. I know the update part should be s.th like this:

```
UPDATE backup.tableX SET columnX=(SELECT main.tableX.columnX FROM main.tableX WHERE main.tableX.id=backup.tableX.id)'
```

But I don't know how to tell this (in my C code), i.e., how to write **if main db is changed then go and update the slave db..**?  for example, in PHP, you can check if a table is updated with `if(mysql_affected_rows ($link)>0) {
}`.. I want it's equivalent in C.

Thanks,

Comment: See [triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), or the [session extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/sessionintro.html).

Comment: @CL., thanks for your comment. Do triggers work for update on different databases? I thought it works if e.g., we want to update a table based on a change in another table within the same database.

Comment: No: "The table to be modified must exist in the same database as the table or view to which the trigger is attached." You could work around this with a user-defined function that executes the query on the other DB …